# GWT infinite scroll with discarding start-of-list results

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, web

Looking for a GWT `DataGrid` component which implements infinite scroll, BUT also makes sure to discard the results no longer visible on the screen : such as the previously loaded results that are not shown anymore.

This is to avoid a memory hog.
I've been trying to find this on Google, but no luck so far.
Please note : I could take a JS library and adapt it to what I need, but I don't think it would work good with GWT's `DataGrid` component.

**Edit:** I am interested specifically in an infinite scroll which ALSO discards/releases the topmost results that are not visible (and loads them up as appropriate).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact the [showcase example](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) has an infinite scrolling `CellList`. (you can find the code there).
Although this was done with a `CellList` the same principles should also apply to a `DataGrid`.
Check out the `ShowMorePagerPanel.java` file.

**Update:**
The onScroll function of `ShowMorePagerPanel.java` will add the new records at the bottom. However you can easily change the behavior:

Something along the lines (not tested tough):

```
HasRows display = getDisplay();
if (display == null) {
  return;
}
boolean loadData = false;
// If scrolling up, change newStart
int oldScrollPos = lastScrollPos;
lastScrollPos = scrollable.getVerticalScrollPosition();
// get the current visible Range
Range currentRange = display.getVisibleRange();
if (oldScrollPos >= lastScrollPos) {
  int newStart  = Math.max(
      currentRange.getStart() - incrementSize,0);
  loadData = true;
}

int maxScrollTop = scrollable.getWidget().getOffsetHeight()
    - scrollable.getOffsetHeight();
if (lastScrollPos >= maxScrollTop) {
  // We are near the end, so increase the page size.
  int newPageSize = Math.min(
      display.getVisibleRange().getLength() + incrementSize,
      display.getRowCount());
  loadData = true;
}
if (loadData) {
   display.setVisibleRange(newStart, newPageSize);
}
```

Comment: I know about the example; I'm just really keen on also discarding the topmost elements who are no longer visible. Edited my question to better underline this aspect. GWT Showcase's example keeps the entire list of elements.

Comment: I updated the answer (it is based on the showcase). Not sure if it works tough because I did it only in my head

Comment: Thank you. However, please note this is not that easy. The scroll bar won't look as if there were multiple results in the top part. So a proper implementation will probably need to take this into account, and perhaps put an empty div or something in the top part, as large as the missing results, or something like this ?

Comment: You are right. You could maybe access the DOM Element of the `Scrollpanel` directly to set the height to a large value based on the number of values and the scroll position you have.